# ImageResizer does not redirect local image url to azure cdn url?

Tags: imageresizer

I have the following configured in my web.config:

```
<resizer>
    <clientcache minutes="1440" />
    <plugins>

    </plugins>

  <plugins>
    <add name="AzureReader2"
         connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccountname;AccountKey=myaccountkey="
         endpoint="https://az824306.vo.msecnd.net/"
         prefix="~/" />
  </plugins>
    </resizer>
```

I have a directory called `bdgtpd` under the root of my website and in there I have one image `40420_1.png`.

I also have this image on azure located at:

`https://az824306.vo.msecnd.net/bdgtpd/40420_1.png`

Initially, I had my src set to `https://az824306.vo.msecnd.net/bdgtpd/40420_1.png`, but when I tried to apply something like `https://az824306.vo.msecnd.net/bdgtpd/40420_1.png?width=300`, it did not work.

So then I set it to:

`<img src="~/bdgtpd/40420_1.png?width=300 />`

and this does resize the image, but when I look in the chrome console, I can see it is grabbing the image from my local folder.  Maybe I don't understand the AzureReader2 plugin, but I thought it when it sees:

`http://localhost/bdgtpd/40420_1.png?width=300`, this would be fetch the image from  `https://az824306.vo.msecnd.net/bdgtpd/40420_1.png` and apply the transformation.

Am I setting my `src` right? Should it be a local url or the cdn url?

Ok, so I deployed ImageResizer along with AzureReader2 to my staging server and I am pointing my images to my staging server.  When I set the prefix to `~/`, the site threw 404 error and there were messages such as `Blob Not Found`.  All the images on the home page are in the CDN.  When I make the prefix `~/azure/`, it works fine, so I am not sure what is going on here.

I was looking at the could architecture documentation, but I am confused on a couple things:

1. Right now I have one image that has the `~/azure/` prefix path set, so when I look in the chrome console under the network tab, I see the initiator is my staging server path, but the image is actually being pull from the cdn.  It would be great to have a simple explanation of what is happening.
2. When I use clientcache, if a user requests the same image from the cdn, how is the image delivered?  I wasn't sure exactly how this works?

Thanks so much

Comment: Why would you expect ImageResizer to issue a redirect when a local copy is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ImageResizer is running on localhost (for example), then your URLs should point to localhost. Azure doesn't have any magic ability to understand ImageResizer commands and execute them; you have to talk to the server with ImageResizer installed.

You should configure AzureReader2 with a prefix (like /azure/), although it appears you've discovered that this works?